# Unicode questions

Tags: c#, java, c++, unicode

1.)What is the difference between C# and Java Unicode ?
2.)Is C++ Unicode limited to only Windows applications ?
3.)Do i always have to add specific C++ package of code that differs from usual to be able to use Unicode in C++ ?
4.)What Unicode language is the most supported on all platforms ?
5.)Did Microsoft start this Unicode trend or are there any other older Unicode languages besides .NET and Java that supported Unicode from ground up ?

Comment: It would be better to have asked 5 separate questions each getting its own answer, than one big one like this that will probably not get an answer.

Comment: You are right, but i tried anyway to have it all on 1 place and i don't expect everybody to answer all of them, but i expect at least 1 per user who gives a answer to my question.

Comment: I assume what you call "Microsoft Unicode" is simply a 2-byte character as it is used in the "wide strings" in Windows.

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, my first thought was "hey, this should be five questions", but the question as a whole does sort of hang together (mostly).

Comment: How do i make a program in C++ that supports Chinese or Arabic without using Visual Studio and Microsoft ?

Comment: @revvs: With respect, I recommend that you stop commenting on this question and its answers and actually go *read* the various resources people have given you links to. Right now, you have a misunderstanding of what Unicode is (which is fine, a lot of people do). Go off, do your reading, and then if you have additional questions, ask them. You're not going to get a good understanding of it through a fragmented series of comments strewn throughout this question and its answers, trying to is going to waste your time.

Comment: I can use Unicode, i am just saying that C++ has big problems with it, unless you are strictly Microsoft.

Comment: @revvs: And the people answering this question are clearly saying to you: No, you just have to handle it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unicode is a standard that is independent of C#, Java, or any other programming language.
2. No.
3. You don't, if your compiler/system supports unicode, this will work:

   ```
   ofstream fout("aaa.txt");
   fout << "Hi, привет\n";
   ```
4. English.
5. No. Unicode was supported by C since the dawn of time.

**EDIT:** See [Unicode answers](http://utf8everywhere.org/) for portable Unicode solutions in C++.

Comment: Don't you mean `wofstream` and `L"Hi, привет\n"` ?

Comment: For english to work you don't need to develop Unicode any further, version 1.0 would be just fine :)

Comment: 5. If you define the dawn of time as 1991, when Unicode was first defined ;-) and even then, C with null terminated strings is hardly "unicode friendly."

Comment: @MSalters: No, you don't. If you can save the file as UTF-8 and your compiler supports UTF-8, it will work.

Comment: @Dov: My point is that in any compiler that doesn't try to be "too smart" and touch the sequence of bytes representing `Hi, привет` as it stored in the source file, it will work. It's implementation defined though. But it was implementation defined since C was standardized.

Comment: I know, but i need support for all languages, Chinese and such also. And for that i don't find any other way in C++ than to use Microsoft tricks.

Comment: @revvs: what do you call "Microsoft tricks", "Microsoft unicode" etc?

Comment: @revvs: MFC/windows API are just back-ends to render the text to the screen. Since C++ doesn't have standard GUI it doesn't have standard ways to render Unicode. However, as you see in the above example in my code, you can write Unicode to a file without using any "microsoft tricks".

Answer (score 5):

Unicode is not bound to a programming language. You might want to read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to clear things out.

Comment: Good that there are links, but i already made few unicode programs and they work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Japanese developer. I try to answer your questions.

1.)What is the difference between C# and Java Unicode ?

This question is very difficult to answer. When we use UNICODE, there are
many aspects that we have to consider, e.g. Font support, Native Code Mapping, Input Method
...

Simple answer is: both C# and Java (and C/C++) use UTF-16 internally. 
Therefore they are almost same. We have no problem to use UNICODE with them.

2.)Is C++ Unicode limited to only Windows applications ?

C/C++ standard specifies wchar_t as UNICODE character. You can use wchar_t with any C/C++ compilers.

3.)Do i always have to add specific C++ package of code that differs from usual to be able to use Unicode in C++ ?

In order to handle UNICODE correctly, you need to use wide character version libraries.
In C, wprintf, wscanf, ... In C++, std::wcout, std::wcin, ....
(Visual C++ has a UNICODE compile option. you need to check it before compiling)

4.)What Unicode language is the most supported on all platforms ?

If this means 'UTF-8'/'UTF-16', as I already mentioned, the platform use UTF-16 as internal code. But when an application get data from outside or put data to outside, it may need to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 or native encoding.

In Japan, we usually use Shift-JIS encoding (one of our native character encoding) on Windows. But recently many utilities (like text editor) support UTF-16/UTF-8, therefore 
we may not need to convert.

5.)Did Microsoft start this Unicode trend or are there any other older Unicode languages besides .NET and Java that supported Unicode from ground up ?

I think that Windows 2000 would be the first Windows which uses UNICODE internally, Win95/98 use native character encoding (Japanese Win95/98 use Shift-JIS internally).

Answer (score 0):

> 1.)What is the difference between C# and Java Unicode ?

[Unicode](http://unicode.org/) is separate from both languages/environments. Both environments *support* it, and when reading or writing text in one of the Unicode *encodings*, it's important that they both adhere to the spec from the Unicode Consortium.

> 2.)Is C++ Unicode limited to only Windows applications ?

No.

> 3.)Do i always have to add specific C++ package of code that differs from usual to be able to use Unicode in C++ ?

Sorry, don't know this one. (Edit: [ebungalobill says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461398/unicode-questions/4461476#4461476), if the compiler and environment support it and you're using modern constructs.)

> 4.)What Unicode language is the most supported on all platforms ?

You probably mean what encoding. I don't know, but I expect that a platform either does, or doesn't, support the popular encodings (UTF-8 and UTF-16).

If you mean what *human* language, it would be English and most other western languages, but support for eastern languages is also robust at this stage.

> 5.)Did Microsoft start this Unicode trend or are there any other older Unicode languages besides .NET and Java that supported Unicode from ground up ?

Well, Java predates .Net by quite a lot. But Unicode predates them both.

Suggested reading (in order):

1. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode
3. http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html
4. http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html

Comment: I was thinking more about UTF-16, because UTF-8 is extra shit.

Comment: @revvs: *(Please keep your language clean on StackOverflow, this is a professional venue.)* There's nothing whatsoever wrong with UTF-8 if the text you're encoding is mostly in western script; using UTF-16 (for instance) will dramatically and unnecessarily inflate the size of the text (basically doubling it). If the text you're encoding is mostly in eastern script, UTF-8 is a poor choice, because *it* will markedly inflate the size of the text over, say, UTF-16. It's all about using the right tool (encoding) for the job at hand. The end result is the same regardless, Unicode is Unicode.

Comment: yes, but UTF-8 can't display all languages or can it ? And isn't Java using UTF-16 and is alright ?

Comment: @revvs: I refer you back to my suggested reading. **All** UTFs can encode **all** characters in Unicode; UTF-8 and UTF-16 are simply a means of avoiding waste. If you're using UTF-8, most western characters will be encoded in one byte, but most eastern characters will take three or four. If you're using UTF-16, all western characters and quite a few eastern ones will be encoded in two bytes, with some eastern characters requiring three or four. And of course, if you use UTF-32, all characters will require four bytes. If you were encoding English text, that would be *massively* wasteful.

Comment: Thats is all good knowledge, but than in C++ you get out on the screen some jibberish and you don't know why, unless you think of something, when in Java you can write that anywhere, even in code. I need support and quick access to all languages, not just european and western.

Comment: @revvs: *"And isn't Java using UTF-16...?"* No, Java uses Unicode, not UTF-16. Java `char` is four bytes wide, and so can directly contain the four-byte value of a Unicode character. The encoding of a Java source file will vary by platform; it's usually going to be Windows-1252 (a superset of ISO 8859-1) if the original author was using Windows, possibly ISO 8859-1 or UTF-8 if the author is using *nix, etc. By default, `javac` assumes it's reading the default encoding of the plaform, but you can override that: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Comment: @revvs: *"I need support and quick access to all languages, not just european and western."* Again, any UTF will give you that. Choose the one that will give you the most efficient use of memory and processor speed for your task (not that transforming the UTFs is CPU-intensive). Best of luck with it.

Comment: I suggest you try it yourself and than you will see problems with languages other than English in C++, you will need to reorganize everything from start for the program to work.

Comment: @revvs: I'm done, you seem more interested in complaining about C++ than in getting and understanding the answers to the questions you asked. Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 0):

1.)Unicode is language independent
2.)No. see #1
3.) do not know. sorry.
4.)If you mean Unicode version? UTF-8
5.)do not know. sorry.

Comment: Unicode is now in version 5; UTF-8 is an encoding not a version.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is an international standard for assigning numeric values to visible glyphs. There are also standards (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) for representing these numeric values using an ordered list of byte values. Note, there are many other standards for assigning numeric values to glyphs, e.g., ASCII, USASCII, various Microsoft CodePage mappings, not to mention mappings for non-english character sets. 
These values are no programming language dependencies, unicode values are independent of c#, C++, or Java. 
Unlike earlier languages, like C and C++, unicode representation of characters was built-in to Java, so you don't have to do anything 'special' to support unicode. That said, you still have distinguish between the unicode 'value' for a character and how this 'value' is represented in your data file. E.g., a data file containing ASCII characters can be read into Java Strings but you have to tell Java that you are reading a file containing ASCII mappings not one containing some other mapping. (btw, the UNICODE folks made that easy as the mapping for the first 128 ASCII characters is the same in ASCII and UNICODE and moreover, the representation of these 128 characters in UTF-8 is also equivalent to ASCII - thus, any ASCII data can be treated as UTF-8 encoded UNICODE).

Comment: Java is very cool, but C++ isn't build from ground up as Unicode, while Java always adds the newest version of Unicode.

Comment: @revvs: You are deluded if you believe Java offers anything like full Unicode support. Java doesn’t even have support for Unicode 3.1 properties, let alone anything from the current decade, century, and millennium. Java is a very poor language for dealing with Unicode.